# How to create bulk parent child relationship(join) in Elastic Search PHP while creating mapping and indexing

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I want to create documents with parent child relationship.

I have data like below,

Parent Document data with parent_id = null

```
{
            "id": 1,                
            "workflow_name": "Diwali",
            "list_name": "number",
            "list_id": "798",
            "msgType": "Promotional - National",
            "sender_id": "MANISH",
            "submit_date": "2017-11-06 14:09:56",
            "dlrdatetime": "2017-11-06 14:10:06",
            "split_count": 1,
            "error_code": "Waiting",
            "error_text": "-",
            "currency_used": "0.2000",
            "text_type": "text",
            "error_code_status": null,
            "origin_type": "1",
            "api_response_id": 1,
            "response": null,
            "parent_id": null,
            "is_test": 0,
            "link": null,
            "type": 2,
            "message_text": "Hi This is text message",
            "status": null,
            "winner_branch": null,
            "instance_id": "724e540394481746",
            "created_at": "2017-11-06 14:10:06",
            "updated_at": "2017-11-06 14:10:06",
            "branch_id": 0
        }
```

Child Document data with parent_id = 1

```
 {
            "id": 1,                
            "workflow_name": "Diwali",
            "list_name": "number",
            "list_id": "798",
            "msgType": "Promotional - National",
            "sender_id": "MANISH",
            "submit_date": "2017-11-06 14:09:56",
            "dlrdatetime": "2017-11-06 14:10:06",
            "split_count": 1,
            "error_code": "Waiting",
            "error_text": "-",
            "currency_used": "0.2000",
            "text_type": "text",
            "error_code_status": null,
            "origin_type": "1",
            "api_response_id": 1,
            "response": null,
            "parent_id": 1,
            "is_test": 0,
            "link": null,
            "type": 2,
            "message_text": "Hi This is text message",
            "status": null,
            "winner_branch": null,
            "instance_id": "724e540394481746",
            "created_at": "2017-11-06 14:10:06",
            "updated_at": "2017-11-06 14:10:06",
            "branch_id": 0
        }
```

So i have one to many relationship, one parent have many child.

Sample code snippet of for bulk mapping:

```
$mapping['index'] = 'response_packets_index_v5';
    $mapping['body'] = array(
        'mappings' => array(
            'response_packets_v5' => array(
                'properties' => [
                    'id' => [
                        'type' => 'integer'
                    ],
                    'workflow_id' => [
                        'type' => 'integer'
                    ],                                            
                    'parent_id' => [
                        'type' => 'integer',                        
                    ],                       
                    'instance_id' => [
                        'type' => 'text'
                    ],
                    'created_at' => [
                        'type' => 'date',
                        'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
                    ],
                    'updated_at' => [
                        'type' => 'date',
                        'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
                    ],
                    'branch_id' => [
                        'type' => 'integer'
                    ]
                ]
            )
        )
    );

    $client->indices()->create($mapping);
```

Code snippet of for bulk indexing:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++) {
        $params['body'][] = [
            'index' => [
                '_index' => 'response_packets_index_v5',
                '_type' => response_packets_v5',                    
                'routing' => 'company',
            ]
        ];

        $params['body'][] = $documentData[$i];
 }
return $client->bulk($params);
```

I already read this article but not helpful for me :https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html

Can any one help me for encounter this problem, Help highly appreciable.

System details:

Operating System ubuntu 16.04,

PHP Version 7.1,

ES-PHP client version 6.0

Comment: Github issue with the  [same exact question](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/issues/721) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems that I see in your specification is that you are not defining a parent-child relationship. In order to do so, you need to use the "join" datatype. That is, in your mapping you need to create a field that specifies whether your document is a parent type or child type. Check below:

```
"properties": {
            "doc_identifier" : {
                "type": "join",
                "relations": {
                    "parent_doc": "child_doc"
                }
            },
            "workflow_id" : {"type" : "keyword"},
            other fields...
}
```

Furthermore, instead of creating a "parent_id" field, you need to specify de parent_id in the child as following:

```
{"doc_identifier" : {"name" : "child_doc", "parent":"parent_id_value"}, "workflow_id": "foo", ..., other fields,...}
```

Finally, when indexing a parent you don't need to add information from the  child.